# String search/ indexing in a file using C++

Tags: c++, string, search

I am using the following code which searches the file and provides the data and associated line number. But is this code fast enough in case of hundreds of thousands of lines? My PC literally froze for a few seconds. I need to search pair of integers and return its RHS value after comma (some statistical stuff), but with the following code I could able to return the whole line.

1. Is it good idea in terms of fastness to parse the returned data using `split` functions and get my RHS value

OR

2. Directly get RHS value based on LHS argument. (Well I am unable to do this)

Can anyone help me in achieving any one of the above two?

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

    int main()
    {
        std::ifstream file( "index_hyper.txt" ) ;
        std::string search_str = "401" ;
        std::string line ;
        int line_number = 0 ;
        while( std::getline( file, line ) )
        {
            ++line_number ;
            if( line.find(search_str) != std::string::npos )
                std::cout << "line " << line_number << ": " << line << '\n' ;
        }
    }
```

Here is my content of `index_hyper.txt` file:

```
18,22
20,37
151,61
200,62
156,63
158,64
159,65
153,66
156,67
152,68
154,69
155,56
156,14
157,13
160,122
161,1333
400,455
401,779
402,74
406,71
```

Comment: What's RHS and LHS ? What output do you want for what input ?

Comment: This code with this file froze your computer? I'm surprised at that. Sure it wasn't the virus checker?

Comment: RHS is Right Hand Side, LHS is ...

Comment: If you observe my contents of file: 401,779 - here LHS (Left Hand Side) = 401 and RHS (Right Hand Side) after comma is 779. And the input will be 401, output has to be 779.

Comment: John, this is a sample file after 10 seconds of iteration, the result will be of lakhs of lines, and that did froze my PC

Comment: So you're saying `index_hyper.txt` is getting auto-generated by some other process ?

Comment: @P0W Right and after that process is complete, I wanna check for which input what is the output...

Comment: What's the file size (`index_hyper.txt`) ?

Comment: As of now its `1.7 MB`

Comment: @user2754070 ahh, it not that big, something else is causing the problem. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7841903/1870232)

Comment: Well, can you please get to my code and parse the output

Comment: 1.7MB? grep would parse that file very fast, no need to write a program to do that

Comment: Read the whole file into memory and then parse it in memory to speed it up.  As is, you are spending a lot of time doing I/O operations.  Try profiling it to see where the time is being spent.

Comment: @DarylHanson, streams are buffered. There is less I/O context switching here than you seem to think.

Comment: @AdamBurry: true, the I/O is buffered; but the buffering size is probably only a memory page in size.  Profiling would be the clearest indicator of where the time is being spent.  It could also be from the getline or find methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, don't start breaking the string up into
smaller pieces (substrings) until you need to.  And start by
specifying exactly what is wanted: you speak of RHS and LHS, and
talk of "get RHS value based on LHS argument".  So: do you want
an exact match on the first field, a substring match on the
first field, or a substring match on the entire line?

At any rate: once you have the line in `line`, you can easily
separate it into the two fields:

```
std::string::const_iterator pivot = std::find( line.cbegin(), line.cend(), ',' );
```

What you do then depends on what your criterion is:

```
if ( pivot - line.cbegin() == search_str.size() &&
        std::equal( line.cbegin(), pivot, search_str.begin() ) ) {
    //  Exact match on first field...
    std::cout << std::string( std::next( pivot ), line.cend() );
}

if ( std::search( line.cbegin(), pivot, search_str.begin(), search_str.end() ) != pivot ) {
    //  Matches substring in first field...
    std::cout << std::string( std::next( pivot ), line.cend() );
}

if ( std::search( line.cbegin(), line.cend(), search_str.begin(), search_str.end() ) != line.cend() ) {
    //  Matches substring in complete line...
    std::cout << std::string( std::next( pivot ), line.end() ); }
}
```

Of course, you'll need some additional error checking.  What
should you do if there isn't a comma in the line (e.g. `pivot ==
line.end()`), for example? Or what about extra spaces in the
line.  (Your example looks like numbers.  Should `"401"` match
only `"401"`, or also `"+401"`?)

Before going any further, you should very carefully specify
exactly what the code should do, for all possible inputs.  (For
most possible inputs, of course, the answer will probably be:
output an error message with the line number to `std::cerr` and
continue.  Being sure to return `EXIT_FAILURE` in such a case.)

Comment: Superb! James its one value as input and its associated RHS as output, one more thing any/ all input values are unique. Can you please put it in my code, I am getting lots of errors even though I include `algorithm.h`

Comment: What kind of errors?  Except for an obvious typo, the only problem I encounter is that the compiler cannot instantiate `std::equals`, because `pivot` is a `const_iterator`, but `line.begin()` is non-const.  You can correct this in several ways: in C++11, either make `pivot` `auto` (so it will be a non-const iterator), or use `cbegin()` and `cend()` everywhere on `line`, once you've read it.  In pre C++11, the simplest is to declare `pivot` as a non-const iterator (or since you're going to be using `line.begin()` several times, you can save it in a `const_iterator`, and use that.

Comment: I've edited to answer to reflect the necessary fixes so that it compiles and works (for me).

Comment: Thanks! I am on Linux Env and using NetBeans IDE, I presume `std::next` is been included in `iterator.h` I've included that, but still - `unable to resolve identifier 'next'`

Comment: Well I've got 2 errors: 

Error-1: `main.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘equal(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)’`



Error-2: `main.cpp:28: error: ‘next’ is not a member of ‘std’`

Comment: @user2754070 There is no file `iterator.h`.  You should be including `<iterator>` and `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the work of the code above with:

```
grep -n "^401," index_hyper.txt
```

If you want to output just the RHS, you can:

```
grep  "^401," index_hyper.txt | sed "s/[^,]*,//"
```

If you are on a Windows platform without sed, grep, bash, etc. then you can easily access unix tools by installing [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

Comment: And how is this related to `C++` ?

Comment: @P0W, It is not. It is related to the problem specification.

Comment: Why not simply `sed -n 's:/^401,//p' index_hyper.txt`?  That will probably be at least as fast as anything he can write.  But presumably, in real life, he'd like to detect syntax errors, and output a message to standard error in such cases.  (Otherwise, why worry about C++, when there is such a simple solution already available?)

Comment: @JamesKanze, thanks for the simplification. Why C++? Well, the question does not say why C++. Without a reason given, it is reasonable to assume there is none. "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

Comment: @AdamBurry :-).  Yes.  Since he mentions his "PC", it's likely that he's running Windows.  In which case, he probably doesn't have very much else but C++.  (I'll admit that even with error checking etc., I'd knock off a Python script if I couldn't do it with the shell tools.  No  point in cranking up the compiler for anything this small.)